# Find two vectors in $P$ and check that their sum is not in $P$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be the plane in $R^3$ with equation $x + y - 2z = 4$. The origin $(0,0,0)$ is not in $P$! Find two vectors in $P$ and check that their sum is not in $P$.

Is this correct?
Two vectors that are in $P$ are $<1, 1, -1>$ and $<6, 4, 3>$ because they satisfy the equation. The sum of these two vectors is $<7, 5, 2>$ and this vector is not in $P$ because it doesn't satisfy the equation.
Is this what the question is asking me to find?

Comment: Technically, yes, but I think the question is suggesting that you find a simpler pair of vectors whose sum is $(0,0,0)$.  However this is impossible, so your solution is about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, say you have two vectors $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ which are both in $P$.  Then you have $x_1 + y_1 - 2z_1 = 4, x_2 + y_2 - 2z_2 = 4$.  Adding these together you get $(x_1 + x_2) + (y_1 + y_2) - 2(z_1 + z_2) = 8$, so the sum of the two vectors, $(x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2)$, is not in $P$.

Comment: So that means any two vectors that are in P when you add then they won't be in P?

Comment: That's right.  What's more, that will hold for any plane $P$ that doesn't pass through the origin.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your solution is correct.