# Will the sum of two vectors lying in a plane not passing through the origin, give a vector in the same plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

By the triangle law of addition of vectors, the sum of two vectors will give a vector that is in the same plane as the original two vectors.

For the plane, $x+y-2z=4$, am I right in considering $(4,0,0)$ and $(0,4,0)$ as vectors ? I am confused because , their sum is $(4,4,0)$ and it does not lie in the same plane as $x+y-2z=4$.

Please do not mark this question as duplicate. I know this has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672146/find-two-vectors-in-p-and-check-that-their-sum-is-not-in-p?r=SearchResults)  and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112503/what-does-it-mean-for-a-vector-to-be-in-a-plane). I did not get a convincing answer in any of those links. Hence I am re-posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors $(4,0,0)$ and $(0,4,0)$ are not in the plane $x+y-2z=4$, indeed they indicate points on that plane and since this plane doesn't pass through the origin their sum don't lie in the same plane.

Note that only when we have a plane passing through the origin, as for example $x+y-2z=0$, then for any pair of vectors on the plane also their sum lie on that plane.

With reference to the plane $x+y-2z=4$, we can select two points on that plane as for example $(4,0,0)$ and $(0,4,0)$ therefore their difference $(4,-4,0)$ represents a vector parallel to the given plane.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. 
Can you please mention a vector which is "in" the plane $x+y-2z=4$ ?

Comment: @rikodousennin The fact is that, vectors never can be on the plane if the plane doesn't pass through the origin. Taking the difference of two points on the plane  we obtain a vector parallel to that plane.

Comment: Oh okay. If I am right, Vectors are objects with magnitude and direction . If so,
why can't we have a vector on a plane not passing through the origin ?

Comment: @rikodousennin  The fact is that we can think to vectors as arrow which start at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your plane is $ax + by + cz = d$, and you have two points on the plane $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. Then, the point $(x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2)$ lies on the plane if:

$$a(x_1 + x_2) + b(y_1 + y_2) + c(z_1 + z_2) = d$$

Since $$a(x_1 + x_2) + b(y_1 + y_2) + c(z_1 + z_2) = (ax_1 + by_1 + cz_1) + (ax_2 + by_2 + cz_2) = d + d = 2d$$ that means that we need $d = 2d$, which only works for $d = 0$. In other words, the plane must pass through the origin.

Comment: Thanks. 
However, @user's answer says that $(4,0,0)$ and $(0,4,0)$ are just points on the plane $x+y-2z=4$. 
So , I am confused.

Comment: @rikodousennin Usually, we view a vector as starting at the origin and going to (x,y,z). In that case, if your plane doesn't pass through the origin then it does not contain the 'full' vector arrow, only the tip. That's why we both talked about points rather than vectors.

Comment: thanks a lot for clarifying my doubt.